# Loop through children items property. Share logic for items with same behaviour

Tags: qt, qml

Seems that can loop through the item hierarchy within the item like this:

```
Flickable {
    id: flicktest
    x:0
    y:0
    width: 100
    height: 100
    contentWidth: 200
    contentHeight: 200
    function logallitems()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        {
            console.log("item "+i);
            console.log(children[i].propname );
        }
    }
    Text{
        id: dummy1
        x: 10
        y: 10
        property string propname :"hey1"
        text: propname + " !!"            
    }
    Text{
        id: dummy2
        x: 10
        y: 30
        property string propname :"hey2"
        text: propname + " !!"            
    }
    Text{
        id: dummy3
        x: 10
        y: 50
        property string propname :"hey3"
        text: propname + " !!"          
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: { flicktest.logallitems() ;}
    }
}
```

Got the example from [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/43334/solved-iterate-through-children-of-a-qml-item/2)

What I would like to do is to have a function that applies logic to the component with the component reference passed as argument, meaning that the `logallitems` would be defined out of the scope of the item that will be looped through, and an item can be passed in as an argument so that the function can be called for any item, like approximately, with the `controlToLoopThrough` passed as argument not working code below:

```
function logallitems(controlToLoopThrough)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < controlToLoopThrough.children.length; i++)
    {
        console.log("item "+i);
        console.log(controlToLoopThrough.contentItem.children[i].propname );
    }
}
```

Is this even possible? I find this very useful if the same logic needs to be applied to many of the controls of the UI that could have the same behaviour  .

Qt creator version 4.15.2, Qt version Qt 5.15.2

Comment: I assume you meant version 5.15.2, not 4.15.2?

Comment: correct, I got Qt creator's version. Corrected in the question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can declare that function in a .js file, import it and call it passing in the id `flicktest`. Give it a shot and if it doesn't work, update your code with what you tried.

Comment: I find that so awesome as I am familiar with JS. I'll check that out. Any resource to check roughly how is it done would be much appreciated. Thanks for your comment :)